# OneNote API: Create notebook without table of contents

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files, microsoft-graph-onenote

I can create OneNote notebook in OneDrive using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks

This notebook is always created with default TOC. Is there any way I can create notebook without TOC or delete created default TOC?

This is needed because I want to upload earlier downloaded content (using OneDrive API) to this newly created notebook and that content has its own TOC. So this default TOC is not needed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is safe to delete the .onetoc2 files. If OneNote doesn't find a .onetoc2 file it will make another. I think the only side effecct is the sections will be in a random order.

Comment: Is there any way to delete TOC? Please note that I am creating a notebook using OneNote API and then trying to delete TOC for this created notebook. I did not find any way to do this using OneNote API.

Comment: The closest call i see is that [deleting the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http); in short, i failed to see a way exists using Microsoft Graph API for OneNote.

Comment: You can only delete files with the OneDrive-API or by accessing your Sharepoint site via a webDAV interface. Interestingly it doesn't seem to matter how may TOC files are present in your notebook from a basic functionality point of view (except for organising the order of sections)

Comment: Thanks. I think I will have to delete the TOC separately.